# How can I serve the same route with fastify/static and a custom route based on header?

Tags: node.js, static-files, fastify

Say for example I have a route along the lines of `/object/:id`, and I want to use fastify/static to serve `STATIC_FOLDER/object/<supplied id>/index.html` by default.
This is really easy, I just register fastify/static with `STATIC_FOLDER` as the root.

I also want to have *the same route* (i.e. `/object/:id`), if the "Content-Type" header is set to "application/json", with custom logic to retrieve the relevant data and return json. This is *also* simple enough to achieve.

But how to I achieve both simultaneously?

If I set up *just* fastify/static, the static file is served perfectly fine. If I also set up a custom route like so:

```js
fastify.get('/object/:id', async function (request, reply) {
  // ... custom logic to get obj by id
  reply.type('application/json').code(200).send(obj)
}
```

Then it only calls that route and returns the json.

Is there any way I can add a filter or something on the route based on Content-Type header?
I tried looking into the [route options documentation](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/#routes-options) but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

With fastify, you can do everything

You need to configure [route constraints](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/#asynchronous-custom-constraints).

They are not a bit verbose, so in this example I used the [`header-constraint-strategy`](https://github.com/Eomm/header-constraint-strategy) plugin that eases a lot the implementation

```js
const path = require('path');
const Fastify = require('fastify')
const fastifyStatic = require('@fastify/static')
const headerConstraintStrategy = require('header-constraint-strategy')

const app = Fastify({
  logger: true,
  constraints: {
    ct: headerConstraintStrategy({ name:'ct', header: 'content-type' }),
  }
})

app.register(fastifyStatic, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
})

app.get('/object/:id', {
  handler: (request) => {
    return { hello: request.params.id }
  },
  constraints: {
    ct: 'application/json'
  }
})

app.listen({port:8080})

// curl http://localhost:8080/object/my-id -H 'content-type:application/json'
// print: {"hello":"my-id"}%
                                                                                                                                                                   
// curl http://localhost:8080/object/my-id                                   
// print: hello%
```